# How to replace the last 3 digits with character 'x'

Tags: jquery, regex

```
var phone = '601112500098';

tried:
(1)
var hidden_number = phone;
hidden_number.replace( 4, "x");10,

(2)
var hidden_number = phone.join('x').substr(-4);
```

I just need to replace the last three digits with `'x'` regardless the length of the phone number.
So that it would change from `601112500098` to `601112500xxx`

How to achieve this in jquery please?

Comment: `hidden_number = phone.replace(/\d{3}$/, 'xxx')`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way using `slice` that doesn't involve any regex (regex is less readable IMO than simple string manipulation):

```
phone = phone.slice(0, -3) + "xxx";
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
var phone = '601112500098';
phone = phone.slice(0, -3) + "xxx";
document.getElementById("output").textContent = phone;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Try `phone.slice(0, -3)`

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks, that seems to work too and it's less verbose.